# Error getting provider_authority in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem trying to get the `provider_authority` to call a `ContentResolver` function:

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authority must be non-empty

code:

```
Account p = getAccountInc(context);
String q = context.getString(R.string.provider_authority);
Bundle extra = bundle;
resolver2.requestSync(p,q,extra);
```

I already look for if  provider_authority is duplicated and in class R the value is:

```
public static final int provider_authority=0x7f0e0036;
```